# How to sort multi dimensional array using array_multisort() for specific key?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have employee data stored in a multidimensional array.
Now I want to sort data via `array_multisort()` function, but I want different result through sorting.
I want sorting according to name or date or numeric values.
Below is the code that in which there is multidimensional array:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>ABC Company</title>
<style>
a
{
    text-decoration:none; color:#000;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width:900px; height:500px; margin:auto; border:1px solid; text-align:center;">
        <h1><strong>ABC-Company</strong></h1>
        <h2>Employees:</h2>
        <table width="100%" border="7">
            <tr style="font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;">
                <td>
                <a href="#">Name</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                <a href="#">Gender</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                <a href="#">DOB</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                <a href="#">Position</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                <a href="#">Start Date</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                <a href="#">Gross Salary</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                <a href="#">Tax</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                <a href="#">Pension</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                <a href="#">Net Salary</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            /*****GROSS SALARY*****
            Creates an array containing the gross salary data for all the employees*/
            $salaries =array(635000.00, 420000.00, 260000.00, 350000.00, 250000.00, 90000.00);

            /*****TAXATION*****
            /* Creates if statements that runs trough the salaries and deducts tax rate accordingly for each employee*/

            /* Aron and taxes*/
            if ($salaries[0] >= 500000) 
            {$tax1=0.45;}
            if ($salaries[0] >= 300000 and $salaries[0] < 500000) 
            {$tax1=0.35;}
            if ($salaries[0] >= 200000 and $salaries[0] < 300000) 
            {$tax1=0.2;}
            if ($salaries[0] >= 100000 and $salaries[0] < 200000) 
            {$tax1=0.1;}
            if ($salaries[0] < 100000) 
            {$tax1=0;}

            /* Britney and taxes*/
            if ($salaries[1] >= 500000) 
            {$tax2=0.45;}
            if ($salaries[1] >= 300000 and $salaries[1] < 500000) 
            {$tax2=0.35;}
            if ($salaries[1] >= 200000 and $salaries[1] < 300000) 
            {$tax2=0.2;}
            if ($salaries[1] >= 100000 and $salaries[1] < 200000) 
            {$tax2=0.1;}
            if ($salaries[1] < 100000) 
            {$tax2=0;}

            /* Daniel and taxes*/
            if ($salaries[2] >= 500000) 
            {$tax3=0.45;}
            if ($salaries[2] >= 300000 and $salaries[2] < 500000) 
            {$tax3=0.35;}
            if ($salaries[2] >= 200000 and $salaries[2] < 300000) 
            {$tax3=0.2;}
            if ($salaries[2] >= 100000 and $salaries[2] < 200000) 
            {$tax3=0.1;}
            if ($salaries[2] < 100000) 
            {$tax3=0;}

            /* Jessica and taxes*/
            if ($salaries[3] >= 500000) 
            {$tax4=0.45;}
            if ($salaries[3] >= 300000 and $salaries[3] < 500000) 
            {$tax4=0.35;}
            if ($salaries[3] >= 200000 and $salaries[3] < 300000) 
            {$tax4=0.2;}
            if ($salaries[3] >= 100000 and $salaries[3] < 200000) 
            {$tax4=0.1;}
            if ($salaries[3] < 100000) 
            {$tax4=0;}

            /* Peter and taxes*/
            if ($salaries[4] >= 500000) 
            {$tax5=0.45; }
            if ($salaries[4] >= 300000 and $salaries[4] < 500000) 
            {$tax5=0.35; }
            if ($salaries[4] >= 200000 and $salaries[4] < 300000) 
            {$tax5=0.2; }
            if ($salaries[4] >= 100000 and $salaries[4] < 200000) 
            {$tax5=0.1; }
            if ($salaries[4] < 100000) 
            {$tax5=0; }

            /* Keith and taxes*/
            if ($salaries[5] >= 500000) 
            {$tax6=0.45;}
            if ($salaries[5] >= 300000 and $salaries[5] < 500000) 
            {$tax6=0.35;}
            if ($salaries[5] >= 200000 and $salaries[5] < 300000) 
            {$tax6=0.2;}
            if ($salaries[5] >= 100000 and $salaries[5] < 200000) 
            {$tax6=0.1;}
            if ($salaries[5] < 100000) 
            {$tax6=0;}

            /*****PENSION*****
            Creates the variabel to deduct pension*/
            $pension = 0.025;

            /*****ABC ARRAY*****
            /*Sorts all the employees in a multiarray with their information. 
            It also does the tax-pension-salary*/

            $abc = array(
                'e_1'=>array('Aron','M','1930/01/25','Manager','1998/01/01',number_format($salaries[0],2,".",","),number_format($salaries[0]*$tax1,2,".",","),number_format($salaries[0]*$pension,2,".",","),number_format($salaries[0]-$salaries[0]*$pension-$salaries[0]*$tax1,2,".",",")),
                'e_2'=>array('Britney','F','2001/05/06','Researcher','2001/03/15',number_format($salaries[1],2,".",","),number_format($salaries[1]*$tax2,2,".",","),number_format($salaries[1]*$pension,2,".",","),number_format($salaries[1]-$salaries[1]*$pension-$salaries[1]*$tax2,2,".",",")),
                'e_3'=>array('Daniel','M','2003/01/15','Officer','2003/12/06',number_format($salaries[2],2,".",","),number_format($salaries[2]*$tax3,2,".",","),number_format($salaries[2]*$pension,2,".",","),number_format($salaries[2]-$salaries[2]*$pension-$salaries[2]*$tax3,2,".",",")),
                'e_4'=>array('Jessica','F','2002/11/21','Officer','2007/02/20',number_format($salaries[3],2,".",","),number_format($salaries[3]*$tax4,2,".",","),number_format($salaries[3]*$pension,2,".",","),number_format($salaries[3]-$salaries[3]*$pension-$salaries[3]*$tax4,2,".",",")),
                'e_5'=>array('Peter','M','1998/01/07','Assisant','2009/09/06',number_format($salaries[4],2,".",","),number_format($salaries[4]*$tax5,2,".",","),number_format($salaries[4]*$pension,2,".",","),number_format($salaries[4]-$salaries[4]*$pension-$salaries[4]*$tax5,2,".",",")),
                'e_6'=>array('Keith','M','2003/07/25','Intern','2012/06/27',number_format($salaries[5],2,".",","),number_format($salaries[5]*$tax6,2,".",","),number_format($salaries[5]*$pension,2,".",","),number_format($salaries[5]-$salaries[5]*$pension-$salaries[5]*$tax6,2,".",",")));

            foreach($abc as &$abct)
            {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                <?php echo ($abct[0]);?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?php echo ($abct[1]);?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?php echo ($abct[2]);?>
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                <?php echo ($abct[3]);?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?php echo ($abct[4]);?>
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                <?php echo ($abct[5]);?>
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                <?php echo ($abct[6]);?>
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                <?php echo ($abct[7]);?>
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                <?php echo ($abct[8]);?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://php.net/usort. If you can articulate your sort requirements, you can make it work with usort()

Comment: It will be better if you will give example for my array 
@MikeB

Comment: @Akmal why don't you read the manual and try it for yourself

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to alter your $abc array so that each sub-array is also an associative array, such that the keys that may be used for sorting are specified as strings which are more readily meaningful the numeric indices, as follows in this simple data example:

```
$abc = array(   'rec_1' => array('fn'=>'Aron','ln'=>'Michaelson'),
                'rec_2' => array('fn'=>'Abbey','ln'=>'Drake'),
                'rec_3' => array('fn'=>'Alice','ln'=>'Peterson'));
```

$abc is thus an associative array whose sub-arrays have keys that easily allow for the data to be sorted by firstname ('fn') or by lastname ('ln').

An elegant way to sort, for example by lastname, is to use a closure, as follows:

```
function build_sorter($key) {
    return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
        return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
    };
}

usort($abc, build_sorter('ln'));
```

build_sorter takes a key as a parameter and that argument will be a bound variable for the closure that the function returns. usort will make use of that closure, which represents a comparison function whose return value is an integer indicating whether the values being compared are identical or if one is greater than the other.

The results may be obtained by the following code:

```
foreach ($abc as $item) {
    echo strtoupper($item['ln']) . ', ' . $item['fn'] . "\n";
}

// output:

DRAKE, Abbey
MICHAELSON, Aron
PETERSON, Alice
```

If for some reason, you'd rather use functions with names, you could also achieve the same results using this sort of code:

```
function SortByLname($a,$b) {
    return strnatcmp( $a['ln'], $b['ln'] );
}
usort($abc, "SortByLname");


foreach ($abc as $item) {
    echo strtoupper($item['ln']) . ', ' . $item['fn'] . "\n";
}
```

Note: that strnatcmp is helpful dealing with data that may contain numeric strings and the comparison will be more in line with what we would naturally expect from the way human beings order such values.  You may review these examples at http://3v4l.org/fng8h and also at http://3v4l.org/QYt9S